# Относительный путь к файлам в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Звуковой файл лежит здесь:

```
C:\Users\Vesbat\Desktop\animation_Zews\sounds\eminem.wav
```

Как мне в программе задать относительный путь? Чтобы при переносе на другой компьютер, программа продолжала выполняться. Если прописываю полностью, все работает.

А так нет:

```
QSound *dialog = new QSound("./sounds/eminem.wav");
```

В файлы ресурсы запихнуть не могу (общий вес звука ~150мб).

Comment: Файл проекта лежит в папке "animation_Zews"

Comment: А в какой папке ехе?

Comment: @gil9red
C:\Users\Vesbat\Desktop\build-rpg_game-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug

Comment: @gil9red
Это на стадии разработки, а потом будет иерархия такая:

game.exe 
image
sounds

т.е. будут лежать рядо и exe и директории

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Путь к папке в которой лежит исполняемый файл можно получить из QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath (см. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath ).

Решение проблемы различия относительных путей в случае отладки приложения и распространяемой версии, может решаться оп разному. 
Например:
define для отладочной версии; 
установка output directorry, не в ..\debug, а в папку с рабочими файлами; 
Специальный ключ в реестре (QSettings), который указывает путь к папке;
...

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете указывать относительный путь от бинарника, откуда его запускаете. Текущий путь бинарника можно узнать так

```
QDir::currentPath()
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdir.html#currentPath

Answer (score 1):

Относительный путь от бинарника должен быть

Answer (score 1):

"Относительный путь от бинарника должен быть"

"Относительный путь отсчитывается не от .exe, а с уровня выше (это папка с make-файлами, которая задается при создании проекта у компилятора, что-то типа build-TestWidjets-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MinGW_32bit-debug)"

При создании проекта без Qт (без QFile) в релизе (папка "build-...-release") - относительный путь от бинарника, а не уровня выше, а вот в самом проекте Qt - на папку выше. При этом файл должен быть и в самом проекте, и в релизе. Либо бинарник просто копировать из релиза в проект, тогда он путь увидит, иначе в исходнике нужно будет переписывать путь под бинарник.

Comment: Пожалуйста, укажите прямо в ответе, чем ваше решение лучше или отличается от предложенных в ранее данных ответах.

Answer (score 0):

Относительный путь отсчитывается не от .exe, а с уровня выше (это папка с make-файлами, которая задается при создании проекта у компилятора, что-то типа build-TestWidjets-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MinGW_32bit-debug)